# Binary Grouping in R

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose I have two vectors of same dimensions:

```
x <-c(0.49534,0.80796,0.93970,0.99998)
count      <-c(0,33,0,4)
```

How can I group the vectors 'x' into two vectors:

1. Vector `grzero` that contain value in x with `count` value greater than 0 and
2. Vector `eqzero` with value in x with `count` value equal to zero.

Yielding

```
> print(grzero)
> [1] 0.80796 0.99998
> print(eqzero)
> [1] 0.49534 0.93970
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, I feel like linux and unix tags could be dropped in this case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
grzero <- x[count > 0]
eqzero <- x[count == 0]
```

Why this works is because expressions like `count > 0` evaluate to a vector of Booleans, so `count > 0` is `FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE` and `count == 0` is `TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`. Then you index vector `x` with Boolean vector and get only those elements for which corresponding value of Boolean vector is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

split may be useful,

```
split(x,c("eqzero","grzero")[(count>0)+1])
```

this is a bad hack though...